# Laravel 5 - Request::Method() returns wrong request type and Input::all() returns empty

Tags: php, laravel, post, laravel-5, get

After I deploy my Laravel web application to my host, my code was not work as local. I have a form and `POST` it to a route, it calls a controller that handles any type of requests. I want to react for each type of request, but `Request::Method()` function returns `GET`.

Route:

```
Route::any('/', [
'as' => 'root', 'uses' => 'WelcomeController@index']);
```

Blade:

```
<form action="{{ URL::route('root') }}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="newsId" value="{{ $newsId }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="orders" id="orders" value="">
    <button class="btn" name="next">NEXT</button>
    <button class="btn" name="save">SAVE</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
if (Request::isMethod('get')) {
    $newsId = (Auth::user()->last_news_id % 100) + 1;
    $sentences = News::find($newsId)->sentences;
    return view('summarizer')->with(['sentences' => $sentences, 'newsId' => $newsId]);
} elseif (Request::isMethod('POST')) {
    return 'post';
}
```

Also I used `Request::Method()` and it retures `GET` for all time!
I tested this codes in my localhost and it works perfectly.

**EDIT:**
I'm surprising that Input::all() returns empty value too. It works in local well.

Comment: To be sure inspect your form and check if there is indeed a `method="POST"` as attribute. Also, maybe you need to capitalize `'get'` in your `isMethod('GET')` check. You never know :)

Comment: @ThomasVanderVeen is right, the parameter should be an "Uppercase request method (GET, POST etc)." (source docs: http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_isMethod)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I capitilize all of them but nothing has been changed.

Comment: Have you got 3 curly braces for csrf token in your code as well? Moreover, you could use `csrf_field` as well. And, keeping individual route definition for GET and POST is a recommended way.

Comment: @Gaurav, as I mentioned in question edit, a bigger problem is about Input::all() empty value, that means no data passed to my controller, even $_GET and $_POST global variables are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way -- Make the Request class dependency injection in index() method. like this

```
public function index(Request $request) {
  if ($request->isMethod('get')) {
   // your code
  }elseif ($request->isMethod('post')) {
   // your code
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best and the easier way is to create 2 routes,

```
Route::get('/', [
'as' => 'root', 'uses' => 'WelcomeController@getFunction']);
Route::post('/', [
'as' => 'root', 'uses' => 'WelcomeController@postFunction']);
```

Then create two function into your controller .
Now try to add dd(Input::all()) into your postFunction to test if The Input:all() is still empty.
On more thing , is better practise to use blade to create your form:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'root','method' => 'post']) }}
    //
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Changing the request from http to https fixed it for me. In my case the server forced requests to https. Hope it helps.